# knockout validation is not workong

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I have a form to be validated using knockout JS.The form along with KnockOut JS Script is available here 
        http://jsfiddle.net/gy8qwLk1/
I want to submit the form after validation true to be true.
Here is my script:

```
    /// <reference path="../Scripts/knockout-3.1.0.js" />
/// <reference path="../Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js" />
/// <reference path="../Scripts/knockout.validation.js" />

var customerRegisterViewModel;

function Customervalidate(id, customerName, contactName, address, city, postalCode, country) {
    var self = this;
    self.ID = ko.observable(id);
    self.CustomerName = ko.observable(customerName).extend({ required: { message: 'Customer Name is required' } });
    self.ContactName = ko.observable(contactName).extend({ required: true });
    self.Address = ko.observable(address).extend({ required: true });
    self.City = ko.observable(city).extend({ required: true });
    self.PostalCode = ko.observable(postalCode).extend({ required: true });
    self.Country = ko.observable(country).extend({ required: true });
}


function Customer(id, customerName, contactName, address, city, postalCode, country) {
    var self = this;

    self.ID = ko.observable(id);
    self.CustomerName = ko.observable(customerName).extend({ required: {message :'Customer Name is required' }});
    self.ContactName = ko.observable(contactName).extend({ required: true });
    self.Address = ko.observable(address).extend({ required: true });
    self.City = ko.observable(city).extend({ required: true });
    self.PostalCode = ko.observable(postalCode).extend({ required: true });
    self.Country = ko.observable(country).extend({ required: true });

    self.addCustomer = function () {
        var dataObject = ko.toJSON(this);        

            $.ajax({
                url: '/api/customer',
                type: 'post',
                data: dataObject,
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function (data) {
                    customerRegisterViewModel.customerListViewModel.customers.push(new Customer(data.ID, data.CustomerName, data.ContactName, data.Address, data.City, data.PostalCode, data.Country));
                    self.ID(null);
                    self.CustomerName('');
                    self.ContactName('');
                    self.Address('');
                    self.City('');
                    self.PostalCode('');
                    self.Country('');
                }
            });
        }

    };



function CustomerList() {
    var self = this;
    // observable arrays are update binding elements upon array changes
    self.customers = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.getCustomers = function () {
        self.customers.removeAll();

        // retrieve students list from server side and push each object to model's students list
        $.getJSON('/api/customer', function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                self.customers.push(new Customer(value.ID, value.CustomerName, value.ContactName, value.Address, value.City, value.PostalCode, value.Country));
            });
        });
    };



    // remove student. current data context object is passed to function automatically.
    self.removeCustomer = function (customer) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/customer/' + customer.ID(),
            type: 'delete',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function () {
                self.customers.remove(customer);
            }
        });
    };
}
// create index view view model which contain two models for partial views
customerRegisterViewModel = { addCustomerViewModel: new Customer(), customerListViewModel: new CustomerList(),validateModel : new Customervalidate()  };

// on document ready
$(document).ready(function () {
    //ko.applyBindings(customerRegisterViewModel);
    ko.validatedObservable(customerRegisterViewModel);
    ko.applyBindings(customerRegisterViewModel);


    ko.validation.configure({
        registerExtenders: true,
        messagesOnModified: true,
        decorateElement: true,
        errorClass: 'error',
        insertMessages: true,
        parseInputAttributes: true,
        messageTemplate: 'customMessageTemplate'
    });


});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your function "addCustomer" I don't see anything that checks if validation has failed or not .. and there are a couple of things that need to be worked out as well.

```
  self.errors = ko.validation.group(self);

  self.isValid = ko.computed(function(){     
        return self.errors().length == 0;
  });

  self.addCustomer = function () {
  if(!self.isValid())
  {
    self.errors.showAllMessages(true);
    return;
  }
```

the framework will generate the UI elements required to display validation messages ... so no need to create those up front.

you might need to put in some work to the script but as a starting point please refer to the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wfpacsgw/3/ for a working version of your script.

Comment: It's working good in fiddler .But when I run in visual studio,I'm  hitting 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'group' of undefined' error

Comment: it is likely that the version of ko,ko.mapping and ko.validation libraries used in the fiddler and in your visual studio are different. make sure they are the same.

Comment: They are the same.I just copied your Script and pasted it in visual studio.I look at the references and they are same and available in my Scripts folder

Comment: hmmm ... I believe that message is referring to the line " self.errors = ko.validation.group(self);" and it is thinking ko.validation is not defined. This leads me to believe that the ko.validation library is the one that is missing. I was able to reproduce it in fiddler http://jsfiddle.net/wfpacsgw/4/ (if you look at the chrome developer console you can see the exception there as well).

Comment: It is defined in the "knockout-validation.js" . So you would need to add reference to this library in your web page in order to use it.

Comment: I didn't understand what you said. But tell me how do add referene..Thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95274/discussion-between-sam-c-and-sujay-raj).